# Closing Android Activity opened from Forms.Context.StartActivity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on facebook authentication in a Xamarin forms app and want to use "native" login on each device.

The Facebook SDK (by Xamarin) is not designed for forms since it requires passing in an Android activity that implements some specific interfaces.

However; I was able to get the UI to display using a `custom page renderer` and then in that renderer calling `StartActitivty` with an activity that uses the exact implementation described in the Facebook SDK getting started. https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid

So far everything works perfect. The android app starts, xamarin forms kicks in, the custom page renderer is loaded the login android activity starts and the user logs in with facebook and we get to the `console.writeline` below.

So, how do I dismiss this intent or otherwise get back to xamarin forms?

Do I:

- Dismiss this intent? - if so then what?
- Inject something to "reset" the main page?
- Other?

  ```
  public void OnCompleted (Xamarin.Facebook.Model.IGraphUser user, Response response)
  {
      //TODO: show user details with welcome and button that takes them to main app.
      //TODO: switch back to xam forms from here on out.
      //TODO: figure out how to change the `main` activity to xam forms.

      // 'Me' request callback
      if (user != null) {
          //How do I get back to Xamarin forms from here?
          Console.WriteLine ("GOT USER: " + user.Name);
      } else {
          Console.WriteLine ("Failed to get 'me'!");
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `Finish();`
Anyway, if you want to see exactly how I did it, you can check it here:
https://github.com/IdoTene/XamarinFormsNativeFacebook